# Package 'google-fluentd' has no installation candidate on Debian 10

Tags: docker, debian, fluentd, google-cloud-logging

On attempting to install the Google Logging Agent on Debian 10, I receive the following error.

```
root@10e0e5d1d15d:/opt/app# sudo bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x buster InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-ops-agent-buster-all InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package google-fluentd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'google-fluentd' has no installation candidate
[2021-10-20T13:41:30+0000] google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config installation failed.
```

I am attempting to install this inside a Docker container based on `python:3.6-buster`.

I've double checked the version of Debian:

```
root@10e0e5d1d15d:/opt/app# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Google clearly states that Debian 10 is supported by the logging agent [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging#supported_operating_systems).

**Attempt 2**

So I ran through the troubleshooting guide and verified that the credentials have been installed correctly on the VM. Specifically, that the service account file exists at `/etc/google/auth/application_default_credentials.json` and although not necessary, set in the environment via `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Additionally, I have checked that the service account has the correct permissions: Logs Writer & Monitoring Metrics Writer.

Despite this, when I run the command (as specified in the docs to verify auth scopes (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/authorization):

`curl --silent --connect-timeout 1 -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes`

It returns nothing. An empty result. Not sure why?

When I attempt to install the agent with the `--verbose` flag, I get the following error:

```
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Ign:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-bullseye-all InRelease
Err:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-bullseye-all Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 142.250.179.238 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-bullseye-all Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
+ refresh_failed apt debian
+ local REPO_TYPE=apt
+ local OS_FAMILY=debian
+ fail 'Could not refresh the google-cloud-logging apt repositories.
Please check your network connectivity and make sure you are running a supported
debian distribution. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#agent-os-list
for a list of supported platforms.'
++ date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
+ echo '[2021-10-22T11:29:28+0000] Could not refresh the google-cloud-logging apt repositories.
Please check your network connectivity and make sure you are running a supported
debian distribution. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#agent-os-list
for a list of supported platforms.'
[2021-10-22T11:29:28+0000] Could not refresh the google-cloud-logging apt repositories.
Please check your network connectivity and make sure you are running a supported
debian distribution. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#agent-os-list
for a list of supported platforms.
+ exit 1
```

**Attempt 3**

Ran the following commands:

```
docker run -ti python:3.6-buster bash
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh && bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install --verbose
```

The output:

```
root@9b078fd9d2a7:/# curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh && bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install --verbose
Enable verbose logging.
+ REPO_HOST=packages.cloud.google.com
+ AGENT_DOCS_URL=https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent
+ AGENT_SUPPORTED_URL=https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#agent-os-list
+ AGENT_PACKAGE=google-fluentd
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ [[ '' == *true* ]]
+ ADDITIONAL_PACKAGES=('google-fluentd-catch-all-config')
+ declare -a ADDITIONAL_PACKAGES
+ [[ -f /etc/os-release ]]
+ . /etc/os-release
++ PRETTY_NAME='Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)'
++ NAME='Debian GNU/Linux'
++ VERSION_ID=10
++ VERSION='10 (buster)'
++ VERSION_CODENAME=buster
++ ID=debian
++ HOME_URL=https://www.debian.org/
++ SUPPORT_URL=https://www.debian.org/support
++ BUG_REPORT_URL=https://bugs.debian.org/
+ main --also-install --verbose
+ case "${ID:-}" in
+ handle_debian
+ EXTRA_OPTS=()
+ declare -a EXTRA_OPTS
+ [[ true == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ EXTRA_OPTS+=(-oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1)
+ [[ add-repo also-install == *add-repo* ]]
+ resolve_version
+ [[ latest == \l\a\t\e\s\t ]]
+ AGENT_VERSION=
+ add_repo
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ lsb_release -v
+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main arm64 Packages [303 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 Packages [7735 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main arm64 Packages [14.5 kB]
Fetched 8291 kB in 3s (3264 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
+ apt-get -y install lsb-release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  distro-info-data
Suggested packages:
  lsb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  distro-info-data lsb-release
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 80.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 distro-info-data all 0.41+deb10u4 [6880 B]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 lsb-release all 10.2019051400 [27.5 kB]
Fetched 34.4 kB in 0s (739 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package distro-info-data.
(Reading database ... 24586 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../distro-info-data_0.41+deb10u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking distro-info-data (0.41+deb10u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-release.
Preparing to unpack .../lsb-release_10.2019051400_all.deb ...
Unpacking lsb-release (10.2019051400) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.41+deb10u4) ...
Setting up lsb-release (10.2019051400) ...
+ CHANGED=1
++ grep -o '^[a-z][a-z]'
++ dpkg -l apt-transport-https
+ [[ un == \i\i ]]
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
+ apt-get -y install apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 149 kB of archives.
After this operation, 156 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main arm64 apt-transport-https all 1.8.2.3 [149 kB]
Fetched 149 kB in 0s (3157 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 24604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.8.2.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.8.2.3) ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.8.2.3) ...
+ CHANGED=1
++ dpkg -l ca-certificates
++ grep -o '^[a-z][a-z]'
+ [[ ii == \i\i ]]
++ lsb_release -sc
+ local CODENAME=buster
+ local REPO_NAME=google-cloud-logging-buster-all
+ local 'REPO_DATA=deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all main'
+ cmp -s - /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-logging.list
+ echo 'Adding agent repository for debian.'
Adding agent repository for debian.
+ tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-logging.list
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all main
+ apt-key add -
+ curl --connect-timeout 5 -s -f https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
OK
+ CHANGED=1
+ [[ add-repo also-install == *also-install* ]]
+ install_agent
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Get:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all InRelease [5494 B]
Ign:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all/main arm64 Packages
Get:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all/main arm64 Packages [615 B]
Fetched 6109 B in 2s (2561 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
+ expected_version_installed
++ dpkg -l google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config
++ grep -o '^[a-z][a-z]'
++ sort -u
+ [[ dp == \i\i ]]
+ return
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ apt-get -y --allow-downgrades install google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package google-fluentd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'google-fluentd' has no installation candidate
+ fail 'google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config installation failed.'
++ date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
+ echo '[2021-10-22T13:15:51+0000] google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config installation failed.'
[2021-10-22T13:15:51+0000] google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config installation failed.
+ exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just try to run the image again and [install the agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation) from the start as described in the documentation.** This seems like a simple glitch.

If you encounter any difficulties then try going through the steps in the [fluentd troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/troubleshooting) (very helpful).

To install the agent from scratch you need to run two commands:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install
```

This [will install the latest version of the agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation#joint-install).

If you're still unable to install the agent on this image you can try running  `add-logging-agent-repo.sh` script with `--verbose` flag to get more information (please update your question then and I will try to answer it).

**Here's how I have done it (not issues whatsoever) for your reference:**

So - I created a fresh GCE VM Instance running Container Optimized OS 81.

[image]

After it was created I logged in and ran `docker run -ti python:3.6-buster bash`.

I got

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6-buster
root@7ad208076c02:/#
```

Quick check if fluentd is installed:

```
root@7ad208076c02:/# service google-fluentd status
google-fluentd: unrecognized service
root@7ad208076c02:/# ps ax
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
      1 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
     10 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

It's not (obviously, since it's a python image).

Let's install then:

```
root@7ad208076c02:/# curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh
root@7ad208076c02:/# bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install

Fetched 8469 kB in 2s (4114 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  distro-info-data
Suggested packages:
  lsb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  distro-info-data lsb-release
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 80.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 distro-info-data all 0.41+deb10u4 [6880 B]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 lsb-release all 10.2019051400 [27.5 kB]
Fetched 34.4 kB in 0s (827 kB/s)  
....
....
....

Setting up google-fluentd-catch-all-config (0.8.0) ...
google-fluentd google-fluentd-catch-all-config installation succeeded.
```

Now to start&check the service:

```
root@7ad208076c02:/# service google-fluentd start
[ ok ing google-fluentd 1.9.3: [....] google-fluentd.
root@7ad208076c02:/# ps ax | grep fluentd
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  1562 ?        Sl     0:00 /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby /usr/sbin/google-fluentd --log /var/log/googl
  1565 ?        Sl     0:01 /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby -Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit /usr/sbin/google-flue
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I noticed that you ran a docker container within a GCE VM instance. Is this necessary? I am attempting to run this locally just for testing purposes before deploying into an AWS environment.

Comment: For testing purposes I ran it in GCE but go ahead and run it locally - it's still the same image so you should (in theory) have the same results.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer to run with the verbose flag as you suggested and also carried out the steps in the troubleshooting guide. It's failing slightly differently this time (running locally).

Comment: Please start a new container with `docker run -ti python:3.6-buster bash` and when it starts run the `curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh && bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh --also-install --verbose` inside it and paste entire output into your question. For now it's completely not clear why this happened ?

Comment: Sure, I've just added the output now.

Comment: Friendly bump :) If you still have the time of course..

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to install the lates maybe [installing specific version](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation#install-specific-version) will do... try it and let me know.